# Python: for a list of strings :Pulling the first 3-6 digit number in a string and a second 3-6 digit number in same string seperated by a space

Tags: python

I have loaded a directory into python, which has 135+ files in them, I got the data from each file and put it into an array. the data has 22 lines of (x y) points, in general, they appear as one of:

```
{123.123 123.123} 
{123 123.123}
{123.1 123.123} 
{12 123.123}
```

I need to keep the (x y) points so they belong to only one file. I am trying  to  use a 2D array but i cant pull the first number (x) and the second number(y) due to the differences in the number of digits. I have been working on this for far too long. Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Using Python lingo, what is a 2D array?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `{123.123 123.123}` is of Type `str` :
Remove the first and last char `point[1:-1]` and `split(' ')` on the space.
Convert Resulted List of String Values into Float `float(f)`.
Assign Resulted two Floats to `x, y`.

```
point = '{123.123 123.123}'
x, y = [float(f) for f in point[1:-1].split (' ')]

print('x:{}, y:{}'.format(x, y))
>>>x:123.123, y:123.123
```

Comment: Consider adding a description of what the code does?